# Name PHP specifiers in printf() strings

Tags: php, naming, format-specifiers

Is there a way in PHP to name my specifiers like in Python?

I want this in PHP:

```
$foo = array('name' => 24);
printf("%(name)d", $foo);
```

I couldn't find nothing related on google or in the php manual.

Comment: Since that's not valid PHP (as you said), and thus has no meaning, and thus does not do what you want, how are we to ascertain from it what you're trying to do?

Comment: OK, I figured it out. Took me a bit though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [vsprintf or sprintf with named arguments, or simple tempalte parsing in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701985/vsprintf-or-sprintf-with-named-arguments-or-simple-tempalte-parsing-in-php)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nice question!

You can roll your own without too much trouble by working with regexes. I based the implementation on the idea of calling [`vsprintf`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.vsprintf.php), which is closest to the stated goal among the built-in `printf` family of functions:

```
function vsprintf_named($format, $args) {
    $names = preg_match_all('/%\((.*?)\)/', $format, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

    $values = array();
    foreach($matches as $match) {
        $values[] = $args[$match[1]];
    }

    $format = preg_replace('/%\((.*?)\)/', '%', $format);
    return vsprintf($format, $values);
}
```

To test:

```
$foo = array('age' => 5, 'name' => 'john');
echo vsprintf_named("%(name)s is %(age)02d", $foo);
```

**Update:** My initial implementation was very lambda-happy. Turns out a super basic `foreach` will suffice, which also makes the function usable in PHP >= 4.1 (not 100% sure about the specific version, but should be around there).

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/z1KF4).**

Comment: Nice answer! I wonder if it could be made run faster by not using any regex.

Comment: @gilden: That's a non-issue or, if you prefer, a dangerous path to premature optimization. Is your app going to be CPU-bound formatting strings all day long?

Comment: Of course not, I'm just curious if it makes any difference. I'm guessing not by a margin high enough to consider doing it.

Comment: `echo vsprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo vsprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `vprintf()` every time.  Also I recommend a negated character class `[^)]` with a greedy quantifier instead of lazy matching with a dot.

Answer (score 9):

Use [`strtr`](http://php.net/strtr):

```
$foo = array('%name%' => 24);
strtr("%name%", $foo); // 24
```

You could also [do this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex):

```
"${foo['name']}"
```

Or this:

```
$name = 24;
"$name"
```

Comment: But this discards the other features of `printf()` like padding, number formatting, etc.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski OP does not mention anything about other features, at least not clearly (the python code). Considering that, `strstr` is PHP function which lets you define your own specifiers. At least that was what I was looking for and google ushered me here.

Comment: Nice. Strtr is the way. If you want also sprintf features, use it together: sprintf(strtr($str, $trans), ...)

Comment: `strtr()` does not modify by reference.  This answer would benefit from some explanation and coding improvement so that it doesn't confuse researchers.

Answer (score 9):

You can do it with `sprintf` by numbering the parameters, like so:

```
echo sprintf('hello, %2$s. What is your %1$s', 'age', 'Jesse');
```

Outputs the following string:

> hello, Jesse. What is your age

Comment: He probably meant that you can skip echo if you'd use printf instead.

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` every time.

Answer (score 0):

the closer core function is `vsprintf()` to use an array instead of multiple parameter, but you still have to use numbered parameters.

in the comments of this function docs there is someone who created a function to do what you want [vnsprintf() printf+array+named parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/function.vsprintf.php#87031)