# How to format array out with printf in php

Tags: php, arrays, string-formatting

I know the `printf` statement in PHP can format strings as follows:

```
//my variable 
$car = "BMW X6";

printf("I drive a %s",$car); // prints I drive a BMW X6,
```

However, when I try to print an array using `printf`, there does not seem to be a way to format it. Can anyone help?

Comment: What kind of formatting would you expect to happen on an array?  Something similar to what happens when you `print_r` an array?

Comment: was hoping if i had an array such as //$my_array(3,2,1), i could use printf() as follows //printf("Ready! %s,%s,%s Go!",$my_array) to output // Ready! 3,2,1, Go!

Comment: No, you can't do that... Trust me, you wouldn't want that too. You are a beginner, in few years talk with us, you will see that is not an option. :D

Comment: [`vprintf()`](http://php.net/vprintf)

Comment: **seealso:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701985/vsprintf-or-sprintf-with-named-arguments

Comment: [There is a php function to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13325716/2269902)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's an extract from one of the comments on http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php:

[Editor's Note: Or just use vprintf...]

If you want to do something like:

```
// this doesn't work
printf('There is a difference between %s and %s', array('good', 'evil'));
```

Instead of

```
printf('There is a difference between %s and %s', 'good', 'evil');
```

You can use this function:

```
function printf_array($format, $arr) 
{ 
    return call_user_func_array('printf', array_merge((array)$format, $arr)); 
}
```

Use it the following way:

```
$goodevil = array('good', 'evil'); 
printf_array('There is a difference between %s and %s', $goodevil);
```

And it will print:

```
There is a difference between good and evil
```

Answer (score 6):

Are you looking for something like this using [print_r with true parameter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php):

```
printf("My array is:***\n%s***\n", print_r($arr, true));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't "print" an array just like that, you'll have to iterate through it by using `foreach`, then you can printf all you want with the values. For example:

```
$cars = array('BMW X6', 'Audi A4', 'Dodge Ram Van');
foreach($cars as $car) {
    printf("I drive a %s", $car);
}
```

This would output:

`I drive a BMW X6`

`I drive a Audi A4`

`I drive a Dodge Ram Van`

Comment: This is indeed the most on-topic and least complicated one.

Answer (score 0):

yes

On your html place this:

```
<pre>
  <?php 
   print_r ($your_array);
  ?>
</pre>
```

or on your code only place:

```
 print_r ($your_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

printf does not handle an array recursively. You can however do:

```
$cars=array('Saab','Volvo','Koenigsegg');
print_r($cars);
```