# php sprintf with array

Tags: php, arrays, printf

I have an array witch match string placeholders as follow:

```
"some text %s another text %s extra text %s"
```

and the array:

```
$array[0] match the first %s 
$array[1] match the second %s 
$array[2] match the third %s
```

I thought it could be done using the sprintf function as follow:

```
$content = sprintf("some text %s another text %s extra text %s", $array);
```

but this return the too few arguments error, i tried to use implode:

```
$content = sprintf("some text %s another text %s extra text %s", implode(",",$array));
```

thanks in advance

Comment: **seealso:**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701985/vsprintf-or-sprintf-with-named-arguments

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Use [`vsprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.vsprintf.php) instead of `sprintf`. It takes an array parameter from which it formats the string.

```
$content = vsprintf("some text %s another text %s extra text %s", $array);
```

Comment: yep that's right, thank you, 7 more minutes to accept the answer :)

Comment: in `PHP 5.6.33`, `$content` is the length of  `formatted string`; we can try    `$string = 'Hello %name!';
$data = array(
  '%name' => 'John'
);

$greeting = str_replace(array_keys($data), array_values($data), $string);`  from first comment of above link of `vsprintf`

Answer (score 21):

An alternative to `vsprintf` in PHP 5.6+

```
sprintf("some text %s another text %s extra text %s", ...$array);
```

Comment: This answer works very well. I do not understand that php sprintf document said second parameter is **mixed** type but throwing error if it is an array. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php No where says what this **mixed** is.

Comment: I'd recommend using `...array_values($array)` instead of `...$array` in case your array has named keys (which would result in `sprintf() does not accept unknown named parameters` without the `array_values` wrapper)

Answer (score 3):

Here you have to use `vsprintf()` instead of `sprintf()`.

`sprintf()` accepts only plain variables as argument. But you are trying to pass an array as argument.

For that purpose you need `vsprintf()` which accepts array as argument.

For example in your case:

```
"some text %s another text %s extra text %s"
```

and the array:

```
$array[0] match the first %s 
$array[1] match the second %s 
$array[2] match the third %s
```

To achieve what you want you have to do the following:

```
$output = vsprintf("some text %s another text %s extra text %s",$array);
echo $output;
```

Output:

```
some text match the first another text match the second extra text match the third
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$rv = array(1,2,3,4);
sprintf('[deepak] yay [%s]', print_r($rv, true))
```