# PHP equivalent of Python's `str.format` method?

Tags: php, python, replace, language-comparisons

Is there an equivalent of Python `str.format` in PHP?

In Python:

```
"my {} {} cat".format("red", "fat")
```

All I see I can do in PHP natively is by naming the entries and using `str_replace`:

```
str_replace(array('{attr1}', '{attr2}'), array('red', 'fat'), 'my {attr1} {attr2} cat')
```

Is there any other PHP's native alternatives?

Comment: Are you looking for this http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Comment: **seealso:**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701985/vsprintf-or-sprintf-with-named-arguments

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As PHP doesn't really have a proper alternative to `str.format` in Python, I decided to implement my very simple own which as most of the basic functionnalitites of the Python's one.

```
function format($msg, $vars)
{
    $vars = (array)$vars;

    $msg = preg_replace_callback('#\{\}#', function($r){
        static $i = 0;
        return '{'.($i++).'}';
    }, $msg);

    return str_replace(
        array_map(function($k) {
            return '{'.$k.'}';
        }, array_keys($vars)),

        array_values($vars),

        $msg
    );
}

# Samples:

# Hello foo and bar
echo format('Hello {} and {}.', array('foo', 'bar'));

# Hello Mom
echo format('Hello {}', 'Mom');

# Hello foo, bar and foo
echo format('Hello {}, {1} and {0}', array('foo', 'bar'));

# I'm not a fool nor a bar
echo format('I\'m not a {foo} nor a {}', array('foo' => 'fool', 'bar'));
```

1. The order doesn't matter,
2. You can omit the name/number if you want it to simply increment (the first `{}` matched will be transformed into `{0}`, etc),
3. You can name your parameters,
4. You can mix the three other points.

Comment: what happens when you want to output a pair of curly-braces without it being interpreted as a placeholder for a variable?

Comment: @dreftymac A simple fix would be to match on `(?<!\{)\{\}(?!\})` instead of just `\{\}` (negative look behind/ahead) so `{{}}` isn't being matched then replace all `{{}}` with `{}`. (Sadly it will also leave behind `{{}` and `{}}` but that's fine, right?). Tell me if I should edit my code to reflect that.

Comment: no problem, I guess the basic point I was trying to make is that replicating str.format() in PHP is not a trivial task.

Comment: I mostly needed its basic usages and I'm pretty pleased with how concise it turned out but it sure isn't exhaustive. :) Didn't claim it was. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 11):

[`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) is the closest thing. It's the old-style Python string formatting:

```
sprintf("my %s %s cat", "red", "fat")
```

Comment: I never liked the old %-style formatting but I guess it will do if there is nothing better.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question, but I believe [strtr with replace pairs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) deserves to be mentioned:

> (PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)
>
> strtr — Translate characters or replace substrings
>
> Description:
>
> ```
> strtr ( string $str , string $from , string $to ) : string
> strtr ( string $str , array $replace_pairs ) : string
> ```

```
<?php
var_dump(
strtr(
    "test {test1} {test1} test1 {test2}",
    [
        "{test1}" => "two",
        "{test2}" => "four",
        "test1" => "three",
        "test" => "one"
    ]
));

?>
```

this code would output:

```
string(22) "one two two three four"
```

Same output is generated even if you change the array items order:

```
<?php
var_dump(
strtr(
    "test {test1} {test1} test1 {test2}",
    [
        "test" => "one",
        "test1" => "three",
        "{test1}" => "two",
        "{test2}" => "four"
    ]
));

?>

string(22) "one two two three four"
```

Comment: Since the signature is super equivalent to the `str_replace` one, here is a list of differences between the two methods if someone is interested: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8177376/1524913