# Command in PHP like % in python (parameterized strings)

Tags: php

In python, we can write `COMMAND("%s.pdf"%param)`. How is it possible to do the same in PHP, e.g.

`<iframe src="/example/%user_input.pdf"%param width="100%" height="100px"> </iframe>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vsprintf or sprintf with named arguments, or simple template parsing in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701985/vsprintf-or-sprintf-with-named-arguments-or-simple-template-parsing-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the closest to Python 2 named parameter string formatting is [strtr](https://www.php.net/strtr):

```php
<?php

$params = [
  '%user_input' => 'hello',
];

?>

<iframe src="<?php print strtr('/example/%user_input.pdf', $params); ?>" width="100%" height="100px"> </iframe>
```

This function does simple text replacements. It does not supoort variable type hints.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for sprintf. See the PHP manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

```
`<?php
$num = 5;
$location = 'tree';

$format = 'There are %d monkeys in the %s';
echo sprintf($format, $num, $location);
?>`
```